# Pre calculus Unit Circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

1. Suppose that you did not have the Unit Circle on Circle A, but rather a circle of radius $5$. Will the angle measures in degrees and/or radians change? Why or why not?
2. Suppose that you did not have the Unit Circle on Circle A, but rather a circle of radius $5$. What do you suppose the $x$- and $y$-coordinates will be for that circle in Quadrant I?
3. Consider the two points in Quadrant I on Circle B. What is the special relationship between them? (Consider the relationship between the angles whose terminal sides pass through these points.)
4. Consider the point in Quadrant I that corresponds to the angle $60° =$ . Examine relationship between the angle measures for those in Quadrants II, III, and IV, where the angle is reflected across the y-axis, x-axis, and the origin. What do you notice about the relationship? (Note: Look at the relationship of the angle measures in degrees and radians, and the $x$- and $y$- coordinates.)
5. Consider the point in Quadrant I that corresponds to the angle $30° =$ . Examine relationship between the angle measures for those in Quadrants II, III, and IV, where the angle is reflected across the $y$-axis, $x$-axis, and the origin. What do you notice about the relationship?

[image]

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: So, you want us to do your homework?

Comment: @Carlos i would like the help because i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: @nicole What do you think about question 1?

Comment: No, the angle measures in degrees and radians will not change regardless of the value of the radius, because a revolution of a circle will always be 360˚ or 2π.  @ChantryCargill

Comment: Have you tried drawing the unit circle and the circle of radius $5$ on the same set of coordinate axes?  How are the coordinates related?

Comment: Hey this is super urgent and i really need help

Comment: @nicole, I think you should do some real drawings yourself to figure everything out. You can do it.